# python program showing error invalid literal

Tags: python

This is program is showing error
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "solution.py", line 4, in <module>
       temp=int(input())
        ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2'
      Input (stdin)`

```
n=int(input())
list1=[]
for _ in range(n):
    temp=int(input())
    list1.append(temp)
tupl=tuple(list1)    
p=hash(tupl)
print(p)
```

can anyone tell me what is the syntax error?

Comment: There is no syntax error, you just can't convert an input with spaces directly into an integer

Comment: Try "12" (without spaces) as input.

Comment: Try `temp = input(); list1.append(list(map(int, temp.split())))`. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Enter numbers in two lines: 1<enter>2<enter>